# Crear programa para imprimir factura con código QR

Tags: c#

Tengo un WS que retorna un vector de 100 filas que debo enviar a la imrpesora, una de esas 100 lineas (la linea 30) es un texto que tiene que ser impreso como QR y no como el texto que viene del servicio. Entonces como hago lo siguiente:

1. Un vector de string manar a la impresora.
2. Al enviar para imprimir, que un elemento del vector sea convertido a codigo QR y se imprima eso.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado para lograr lo que buscas?

Comment: En realidad ya tengo el programa funcionando con PrintLib, todo esta OK, el problema es que el código QR que genera e imprime esa libreria no es de "Buena calidad", ya que algunas app lectores de QR no la reconocen o tardan mucho en reconocerlas, es por eso que quiero crear otro programa con otras librerías para ver como me va.

Comment: Pues tu pregunta no está bien formulada..

Comment: para mi si lo esta, ya que lo que tengo no funciona bien, así que solo me queda empezar de cero, y para empezar de cero es que realice la pregunta tal y como lo esta.

Comment: No te queda empezar de cero, porque si tienes algo ya creado, ¿Por qué reinventar la rueda? Si solo quieres implementar un nuevo código para hacer el QR, busca la nueva librería e implementalo. I.e: [QrCode.NET](http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/) o [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)...

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar QR de calidad te recomiendo utilizar [esta herramienta gratuita](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20574/Open-Source-QRCode-Library) que te de múltiples opciones de resolución etc.

Para imprimirla, si el código QR ya tiene calidad no te hace falta modificar el código.

Un saludo.